# Sorting objects by hierarchy (ParentID)

Tags: .net, linq

I have a collection of objects with these fields:

```
MessageID int,
Text string,
ParentMessageID int?
```

Some example data:

```
1 | "Text 1" | null 
2 | "Reply to Text 1" | 1 
3 | "Reply to Text 1 #2" | 1
4 | "Reply to reply to text 1" | 2
```

I want to sort this collection by the parent and child messages, so the IDs would be sorted like this:

```
1
2
4 (child of 2)
3
```

How to do it with LINQ?

```
    var q = from i in _dbContext.Messages where ... orderby ...
```

Comment: you want to sort it by what exactly? Why does 4 come before 3?

Comment: sort be replies on messages (look at ParentMessageID)

Comment: sort by the count of replies? Still this doesn't tell me why 4 would come before 3

Comment: @John: since 1<2 parentID 1 should come earlier. 4 is child of 2 and 3 is child of 1

Comment: I believe this question is almost exactly the same situation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645166/linq-parent-child-relation

Answer (score 1):

You first need a way for each row to contain the entire path up to the root:

```
1 | "Text 1" | "1"
2 | "Reply to Text 1" | "1_2" 
3 | "Reply to Text 1 #2" | "1_3"
4 | "Reply to reply to text 1" | "1_2_4"
```

Either save it directly when you save your comments, or compute it on the fly on the code (kinda expensive). Then it's a simple matter of sorting by this column (as text mind you)

Comment: Definitely very expensive. On a project I worked on we saw very poor performance trying to calculate/sort like this on the fly. Pre-calculating the sort key is much MUCH faster.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a tree, then recursively descend from roots to leafs. There are many ways to do this, here is one:

```
class Message {

    public Message(int message_id, string text, int? parent_message_id) {
        Debug.Assert(message_id < int.MaxValue);
        MessageID = message_id;
        ParentMessageID = parent_message_id;
        Text = text;
    }

    public readonly int MessageID;
    public readonly string Text;
    public readonly int? ParentMessageID;

    public static IEnumerable<Message> OrderByHierarchy(IEnumerable<Message> messages) {

        // Key: ParentMessageID (null substituted with int.MaxValue).
        // Value: All messages sharing this parent.
        var dict = messages.GroupBy(m => m.ParentMessageID ?? int.MaxValue).ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key);

        // For each root, recursively traverse its children.
        return dict[int.MaxValue].SelectMany(root => RecursiveDescent(dict, root));

    }

    static IEnumerable<Message> RecursiveDescent(Dictionary<int, IGrouping<int, Message>> dict, Message parent) {

        yield return parent;

        IGrouping<int, Message> children;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(parent.MessageID, out children))
            foreach (var child in children)
                foreach (var descendent in RecursiveDescent(dict, child))
                    yield return descendent;

    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", MessageID, Text, ParentMessageID == null ? "null" : Convert.ToString(ParentMessageID));
    }

}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var messages = new[] {
            new Message(1, "Text 1", null),
            new Message(2, "Reply to Text 1", 1),
            new Message(3, "Reply to Text 1 #2", 1),
            new Message(4, "Reply to reply to text 1", 2),
        };

        foreach (var m in Message.OrderByHierarchy(messages))
            Console.WriteLine(m);

    }

}
```

This prints:

```
1 | Text 1 | null
2 | Reply to Text 1 | 1
4 | Reply to reply to text 1 | 2
3 | Reply to Text 1 #2 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE (Common Table Expression) in SQL Server, you could achieve what you're looking for - then you could just "persist" this into e.g. a view, and query that view from your Linq-to-SQL code.

```
WITH Hierarchy AS 
(
    SELECT
       ID, ParentID = CAST(ParentID AS INT), MsgText, 
       NodePath = CAST('/' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM    
       dbo.MessageTest 
    WHERE
       ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       m.ID, m.ParentID, m.MsgText, 
       CAST(h.NodePath + '/' + CAST(m.ID AS VARCHAR(5)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM    
       dbo.MessageTest m
    INNER JOIN 
       Hierarchy h ON m.ParentID = h.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY NodePath
```

This gives me an output of:

```
ID  ParentID  MsgText                 NodePath
1   NULL      Text 1    1         /1
2   1         Reply to Text #1        /1/2
4   2         Reply to text #2        /1/2/4
3   1         Reply #2 to Text #1     /1/3
```