# Sorting a list by parent/child relations ship so I have definitely processed a parent before I try to process the child

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a system where people can sent me a `List<ProductCategory>`.

I need to do some mapping to my system and then save these to the database.

The incoming data is in this format:

```
public string ExternalCategoryID { get; set; }
public string ExternalCategoryName { get; set; }
public string ExternalCategoryParentID { get; set; }
```

The incoming list is in no particular order. If `ExternalCategoryParentID` is null then this is a top level category. The parent child relationship can be any depth - i.e. Technology > TVs > Samsung > 3D > 40" > etc > etc

When I'm saving I need to ensure I've already saved the parent - I can't save TVs until I have saved Technology. The `ExternalCategoryID` is likely to be an int but this has no relevance on the parent child relationship (a parent can have a higher or lower id than a child).

How can I order this list so I can loop through it and be certain that for any child, I have already processed it's parent.

The only way I can think of is to get all where `ExternalCategoryParentID == null` then get all where the `ExternalCategoryParentID` is in this "Top Level" list, then get the next set of children... etc. but this can't be the best solution. I'd prefer to sort first, then have a single loop to process. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645166/linq-parent-child-relation) post, but it relies on `createdDate` which isn't relevant to me.

Comment: You are doing what is called "topological sorting on a directed acyclic graph". From Introduction to algorithms, Thomas Cormen: "... Another way to perform topological sorting on a directed acyclic graph is to repeatedly find a vertex of in-degree 0, output it, and remove it and all of its outgoing edges from the graph." So you will do repeated calls anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't so difficult after all. I wrote this function to do it - you pass in the original list and it will return a sorted list.

It works by looping through the list checking if there are any items in the list that have `id == current items parentid`. If there is one, we ignore that item and continue. if there aren't any, we add the current item to the `sortedList` and remove it from the original list and continue. This ensures that items are inserted in the sorted list after their parent.

```
private List<HeisenbergProdMarketplaceCategory> SortByParentChildRelationship(List<HeisenbergProdMarketplaceCategory> heisenbergMarketplaceCategories)
{
    List<HeisenbergProdMarketplaceCategory> sortedList = new List<HeisenbergProdMarketplaceCategory>();

    //we can check that a category doesn't have a parent in the same list - if it does, leave it and continue
    //eventually the list will be empty
    while(heisenbergMarketplaceCategories.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = heisenbergMarketplaceCategories.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (heisenbergMarketplaceCategories.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ExternalCategoryID == heisenbergMarketplaceCategories[i].ExternalCategoryParentID) == null)
            {
                sortedList.Add(heisenbergMarketplaceCategories[i]);
                heisenbergMarketplaceCategories.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check the field value to be null and then set int.max to it and then order by desc to get it at the top.

We can check the `ExternalCategoryID = field.Value ?? int.max` and then `Order by descending`.

Sample :

```
var query = context.Categories.Select(o => new { Obj = o, OrderID = o.OrderID ?? int.MaxValue }).OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderID).Select(o => o.Obj);
```

Comment: The value in ExternalCategoryParentID  has no relevance so I can't order by it. It is perfectly feasible that a child will have a lower ID than its parent. e.g. "TVs" already exists, then we add a new category called "Tech" then we add "TVs" to "Tech". Or the usual situation where the parent is added first, then the child after.

Comment: What I thought is the one which has categoryParentId as null are the new entries and the rest of records which has categoryParentid has tht category in the database already.